# PHP Wordpress: Store time from input as HH:MM:SS.ms

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, time, format

I have a PHP page within wordpress and am wanting the user to input a time, in the format of HH:MM:SS.fff

Note that 'fff' = fraction of a second, to 3 digits.
For example, 1 hours, 30 minutes, 25 seconds and 222 would be.
01:30:25.222

The following process works for integers / floats, but I need to format to be set for a time for this example.

At the top, I get the user_ID and set a variable for existing.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$existing_100MRow = ( get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user-100MRow', true ) ) ? get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user-U100MRow', true ) : '';
```

I then have a form with the following HTML. I've attempted to find the solution, this is why this contains the type as Time.

```
<label for="user-U100MRow"><strong>100M ROW</strong>
    <input id="user-U100MRow" type="time" value="00:00:00" step="1" name="user-U100MRow" value="<?php echo $existing_U100MRow; ?>">
</label>
```

I then set from the input:

```
$_100mRow = ( ! empty( $_POST['user-_100MRow'] ) ) ? floatval( $_POST['user-_100MRow'] )  : '';
```

Then update the user:

```
wf_insert_update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user-100MRow', $_100MRow);
```

I would like the user to be able to enter a time in the format of HH:MM:SS.fff , for this to update and then also show the default value .

i

I've since tried the following:

$_100mRow = ( ! empty( $_POST['user-_100MRow'] ) ) ? MICROSECOND(DATE_FORMAT(( $_POST['user-_100MRow'] ),'%H:%i:%s.%f')) : '';

STILL STRUGGLING. SHOWING NULL IN DB.

Comment: Try just using PHP's date function `date("H:i:s.u", strtotime($_POST['user-_100MRow']));`

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines may help:

```
switch(!empty($_POST['user-_100MRow'))
{
    case true:
        $dt = new DateTime($_POST['user-_100MRow']);
        break;

    default:    
        $dt = new DateTime();
}

$tformat = $dt->format('H:i:s.u');

update_user_meta(
    $user_id,
    'user-_100MRow',
    $tformat 
);
```